# React Bootstrap Navbar wont align right

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I Want a fixed header in application with app name to left and menu options to Right, search in middle (exactly like StackOverflow header).

I get everything aligned to the left. I tried `pullRight`, `pull-Right`, `float-right`, nothing works:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button ,Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown, Form, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

export default class Header extends React.Component {

    style = {
        backgroundColor : '#656D78',
        color: '#656D78',
        height: '50px',
        width: '100%'
    };

    brandStyle = {
        backgroundColor : '#FFCE54',
        height: '100%',
        width: '103px',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#656D78',
        fontWeight: '800',
        fontSize: '30px',
        borderBottom: '2px solid #656D78',
        padding: '9px',
        float : 'left'
    }
    formStyle = {
        float : 'right'
    };
  render(){
    return(
            <Navbar expand="lg"  style = {this.style} >
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home"  style={this.brandStyle}>MYAPP</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Form inline className="float-right" style={this.formStyle}>
                        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2 formStyle" />
                        <Nav.Link href="#home" >Hi, Rag</Nav.Link>
                    </Form>
            </Navbar>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Instead of `float-right`, try using `ml-auto`

Answer (score 2):

inside form use class **ml-auto** to take the nav tag to right

Answer (score 0):

I give you a full example with form how to implement the design. Put the form in the position as I given. Use ms-auto me-auto class to make it aligned center.

```
<Navbar bg='dark' variant="dark" expand="md" fixed="top">
    <Navbar.Brand href="/" style={{ width: 275 }} className="me-5">Logo</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Form className="ms-auto me-auto">
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2 formStyle" />
        </Form>
        <Nav className="">
            <Nav.Item className="">
                <Nav.Link className={textColor} href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link className={textColor} href="/blog">Blog</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link className={textColor} href="/writeups">Writeups</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item className="">
                <Nav.Link className={textColor.concat(" btn")} href="/sign-up">Sign Up</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item >
                <Nav.Link className={textColor.concat(" btn btn-primary")} href="/sign-in">Sign In</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```